# Find clusters with specific value in 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an image/matrix of the size (91*109*91). The image contains voxels with values from 0 to 1. Now I would like to discard all voxels instead of those meeting the following conditions:

1. They have a value smaller than .05
2. They are part of cluster (somehow connected voxels) of minimum 30 voxels with value < .05

At the end, I would like to have a 91*109*91 matrix/image containing only clusters of voxels with a value < 0.05.

I can figure out the first condition, what’s tricky for me is the second condition.

Comment: Could you show us your code and your attempts?

Comment: Look up connected component analysis (a.k.a. labeling).

Comment: [`bwconncomp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) supports 3D. Threshold your image, run `bwconncomp` and discard the components with mass less than 30.

Comment: It works with regionprops(image<.05, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList')